# Change JTextfield after it has been set once

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextfield, gettext

I have a program that is creating a game, and I need it to switch between names in a JTextField in between turns. This is what I have so far:

```
    JTextField curPlay;
    JTextField player1Name;
    JTextField player2Name;
     if (curPlay.getText().equals(player1Name.getText())) {
        curPlay.setText(player2Name.getText());
     }
```

Comment: It isn't working, it sets the JTextField to something else. I'm assuming then that is correct, and that something else must be wrong.

Comment: The information you provided isn't enough. What's `curPlay`? Will it always have the value of player currently playing?

Comment: @JaskaranbirSingh Yes. it starts out with player1Name in it and it needs to change to player2Name